# filter out tags from xml with some condition

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have one requierment where i want to remove some tags from xml based on condition.

Here is my input xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TCXML xmlns="http://www.tcxml.org/Schemas/TCXMLSchema">
<File creation_date="2012-09-20T07:28:47Z" elemId="id280" exportedFileName="sheet 1" last_mod_date="2012-09-20T07:28:48Z" text_flag="8192">

    <GSIdentity elemId="id111" label="R0dB1SzBBT4jNA"/>

</File>
  <File creation_date="2012-09-20T07:18:26Z" elemId="id283"exportedFileName="test part" last_mod_date="2012-09-20T07:18:26Z"  text_flag="8192">

    <GSIdentity elemId="id31" label="SIWBFqLyBT4jNA"/>

</File>
  <File creation_date="2012-09-20T07:21:03Z" elemId="id322" exportedFileName="test part3"  last_mod_date="2012-09-20T07:21:03Z"  text_flag="8192">

    <GSIdentity elemId="id46" label="ycUBFqLyBT4jNA"/>

</File>
  <File creation_date="2012-09-20T07:18:25Z" elemId="id285" exportedFileName="test part2"  last_mod_date="2012-09-20T07:18:25Z"  text_flag="4096">

    <GSIdentity elemId="id29" label="SQRBFqLyBT4jNA"/>

</File>

  <Sheet creation_date="2012-09-20T07:28:48Z" date_released="" ead_paragraph="" elemId="id185"  keep_limit_prop="3" last_mod_date="2012-09-20T07:28:48Z"  object_desc="" object_name="Sheet 1"  ref_list="#id111">

    <GSIdentity elemId="id112" label="R4WB1SzBBT4jNA"/>

</Sheet>


  <PART creation_date="2012-09-20T07:21:22Z" date_released="" ead_paragraph="" elemId="id435"  keep_limit_prop="3" last_mod_date="2012-09-20T07:21:28Z" object_name="dwgTest-AA-dwg1" ref_list="#id29 #id31">

    <GSIdentity elemId="id32" label="SxZBFqLyBT4jNA"/>

</PART>
  <PART creation_date="2012-09-20T07:21:23Z" date_released="2012-09-20T07:21:27Z" ead_paragraph="" elemId="id438"  keep_limit_prop="3" last_mod_date="2012-09-20T07:21:29Z"  object_name="dwgTest-AA-dwg2" ref_list="#id46">

    <GSIdentity elemId="id21" label="itfBFqLyBT4jNA"/>

</PART>
</TCXML>
```

I want to remove those File tags from this xml which are referred in PART with ref_list tags.

I am trying with following xsl,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xmlns:plm="http://www.tcxml.org/Schemas/TCXMLSchema" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="plm:File">

    <xsl:variable name="Ref_List" select="translate(/plm:TCXML/plm:PART/@ref_list,' ','')" />
    <xsl:variable name="currentElementGSId" select="plm:GSIdentity/@elemId" />  
    <xsl:variable name="RefcurrentElementGSId" select="concat(string('#'),$currentElementGSId)" />  
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="((contains($Ref_List,$RefcurrentElementGSId))=true())" >
            </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /> 
        </xsl:copy>         
    </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>   
</xsl:template>
```

Above xsl is working only for one PART in the xml and not all PART tags from the xml , how to loop through all PART tags in the xml.
Thanks for  your help in advance.

I am looking for output for this xml as follows,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TCXML xmlns="http://www.tcxml.org/Schemas/TCXMLSchema">
<File creation_date="2012-09-20T07:28:47Z" elemId="id280" exportedFileName="sheet 1" last_mod_date="2012-09-20T07:28:48Z" text_flag="8192">

    <GSIdentity elemId="id111" label="R0dB1SzBBT4jNA"/>

</File>

  <Sheet creation_date="2012-09-20T07:28:48Z" date_released="" ead_paragraph="" elemId="id185"  keep_limit_prop="3" last_mod_date="2012-09-20T07:28:48Z"  object_desc="" object_name="Sheet 1"  ref_list="#id111">

    <GSIdentity elemId="id112" label="R4WB1SzBBT4jNA"/>

</Sheet>


  <PART creation_date="2012-09-20T07:21:22Z" date_released="" ead_paragraph="" elemId="id435"  keep_limit_prop="3" last_mod_date="2012-09-20T07:21:28Z" object_name="dwgTest-AA-dwg1" ref_list="#id29 #id31">

    <GSIdentity elemId="id32" label="SxZBFqLyBT4jNA"/>

</PART>
  <PART creation_date="2012-09-20T07:21:23Z" date_released="2012-09-20T07:21:27Z" ead_paragraph="" elemId="id438"  keep_limit_prop="3" last_mod_date="2012-09-20T07:21:29Z"  object_name="dwgTest-AA-dwg2" ref_list="#id46">

    <GSIdentity elemId="id21" label="itfBFqLyBT4jNA"/>

</PART>
</TCXML>
```

Comment: Have you noticed that the currently-accepted answer dos *not* produce the provided wanted result?

Comment: When you find fault with an answer, it's considered polite to inform whoever posted it of the error. If there is an error, I'm sure @lwburk would prefer to correct it.

Comment: @Flynn1179, It is a better educational experience if a person finds the error themselves. lwburk is extremely experienced and he had found the cause long before you wrote that comment. Also, he was informed by the OP that his solution doesn't produce the wanted result. So, your assumption that lwburk wasn't informed about the issue, contradicts the facts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input/output do not match your description:

> I want to remove those File tags from this xml which are referred in
>   PART with ref_list tags.

The following XSLT performs an operation equal to that description:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:plm="http://www.tcxml.org/Schemas/TCXMLSchema" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="plm:File">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="/plm:TCXML/plm:PART[contains(
                concat(' ', @ref_list, ' '), 
                concat(' #', current()/@elemId, ' '))]">
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The second template discards any `File` element whose `elemId` is found in the `ref_list` attribute of any `PART` element. All other `File` elements are copied as-is.

**Note**: Your template failed to work as desired because `translate` expects its first argument to be a string; you passed a node list, which was converted to a string [according to the following rule](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-string):

> A node-set is converted to a string by returning the string-value of
>   the node in the node-set that is first in document order. If the
>   node-set is empty, an empty string is returned.

Comment: Updated to remove use of `current` in a match pattern. Saxon happily lets this fly, but it's not allowed by the spec. The expression for matching unwanted elements is the same and no change to the description of the approach is needed.

Comment: thanks for working on my problem, But now with this logic its coping all File elements even if it is found in ref_list attribute of PART element, can you pelase check once.

Comment: @parag - That's not the behavior I'm seeing. Are we sure we're working toward the same goal? I'm placing the `@elemId` of the `File` I want to remove in the `@ref_list` (prepending the `#`) of any `PART`. It's accurately eliminating those elements.

Comment: @parag - Also, double-check that your input matches the supplied input you've given. The solution relies on the supplied structure.

Comment: I am using same input file provided in question and trying to apply this xsl but somehow its not working for  me. 
I want to remove all File elements from xml which are referred in PART element by ref_list attribute.
After applying xsl there should be  only one File element in output xml which is elemId="id111" becasue it is referred in Sheet element.
I hope we are on same page. After applying xsl can you post your output there.

Comment: If i remove current() then its working . I replaced current()/@elemId with variable. Thank you very much

Comment: I see the difference in the light of day. You wanted the ID of the child `GSIdentity`. See my comment above explaining that my understanding was different.

Comment: @parag - Just so we're clear, the difference has nothing to do with the `current` function. The issue is that you wanted to match on the `elemId` of the `File/GSIdentity` but, as I stated in my answer, I thought you wanted to match on the `elemId` of the `File` itself (because I didn't notice the `GSIdentity` reference in your original attempt and your description wasn't specific). Hope that helps you generalize and understand your solution.

Answer (score 2):

**A shorter and simpler, and, most importantly: correct solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:x="http://www.tcxml.org/Schemas/TCXMLSchema">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="x:File">
  <xsl:if test=
  "not(/*/x:PART/@ref_list
                 [contains(concat(.,' '),
                           concat('#',
                                  current()/x:GSIdentity/@elemId,
                                  ' ')
                           )
                 ])">
    <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<TCXML xmlns="http://www.tcxml.org/Schemas/TCXMLSchema">
    <File creation_date="2012-09-20T07:28:47Z" elemId="id280"
      exportedFileName="sheet 1" last_mod_date="2012-09-20T07:28:48Z"
      text_flag="8192">
        <GSIdentity elemId="id111" label="R0dB1SzBBT4jNA"/>
    </File>
    <File creation_date="2012-09-20T07:18:26Z" elemId="id283"
      exportedFileName="test part" last_mod_date="2012-09-20T07:18:26Z"
      text_flag="8192">
        <GSIdentity elemId="id31" label="SIWBFqLyBT4jNA"/>
    </File>
    <File creation_date="2012-09-20T07:21:03Z" elemId="id322"
      exportedFileName="test part3"  last_mod_date="2012-09-20T07:21:03Z"
      text_flag="8192">
        <GSIdentity elemId="id46" label="ycUBFqLyBT4jNA"/>
    </File>
    <File creation_date="2012-09-20T07:18:25Z" elemId="id285"
      exportedFileName="test part2"  last_mod_date="2012-09-20T07:18:25Z"
      text_flag="4096">
        <GSIdentity elemId="id29" label="SQRBFqLyBT4jNA"/>
    </File>
    <Sheet creation_date="2012-09-20T07:28:48Z" date_released=""
      ead_paragraph="" elemId="id185"  keep_limit_prop="3"
      last_mod_date="2012-09-20T07:28:48Z"  object_desc=""
      object_name="Sheet 1"  ref_list="#id111">
        <GSIdentity elemId="id112" label="R4WB1SzBBT4jNA"/>
    </Sheet>
    <PART creation_date="2012-09-20T07:21:22Z" date_released=""
    ead_paragraph="" elemId="id435"  keep_limit_prop="3"
    last_mod_date="2012-09-20T07:21:28Z" object_name="dwgTest-AA-dwg1"
    ref_list="#id29 #id31">
        <GSIdentity elemId="id32" label="SxZBFqLyBT4jNA"/>
    </PART>
    <PART creation_date="2012-09-20T07:21:23Z" date_released="2012-09-20T07:21:27Z"
    ead_paragraph="" elemId="id438"  keep_limit_prop="3"
    last_mod_date="2012-09-20T07:21:29Z"  object_name="dwgTest-AA-dwg2"
    ref_list="#id46">
        <GSIdentity elemId="id21" label="itfBFqLyBT4jNA"/>
    </PART>
</TCXML>
```

**The wanted, correct result (3 of the 4 File elements are r"deleted") is produced:**

```
<TCXML xmlns="http://www.tcxml.org/Schemas/TCXMLSchema">
    <File creation_date="2012-09-20T07:28:47Z" elemId="id280" exportedFileName="sheet 1" last_mod_date="2012-09-20T07:28:48Z" text_flag="8192">
        <GSIdentity elemId="id111" label="R0dB1SzBBT4jNA"/>
    </File>
    <Sheet creation_date="2012-09-20T07:28:48Z" date_released="" ead_paragraph="" elemId="id185" keep_limit_prop="3" last_mod_date="2012-09-20T07:28:48Z" object_desc="" object_name="Sheet 1" ref_list="#id111">
        <GSIdentity elemId="id112" label="R4WB1SzBBT4jNA"/>
    </Sheet>
    <PART creation_date="2012-09-20T07:21:22Z" date_released="" ead_paragraph="" elemId="id435" keep_limit_prop="3" last_mod_date="2012-09-20T07:21:28Z" object_name="dwgTest-AA-dwg1" ref_list="#id29 #id31">
        <GSIdentity elemId="id32" label="SxZBFqLyBT4jNA"/>
    </PART>
    <PART creation_date="2012-09-20T07:21:23Z" date_released="2012-09-20T07:21:27Z" ead_paragraph="" elemId="id438" keep_limit_prop="3" last_mod_date="2012-09-20T07:21:29Z" object_name="dwgTest-AA-dwg2" ref_list="#id46">
        <GSIdentity elemId="id21" label="itfBFqLyBT4jNA"/>
    </PART>
</TCXML>
```